# What's the "reference" refering to in vue functional component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Recently i'm reading the document of Vue, and when i was reading functional component, i found a statement that :

> Note: in versions before 2.3.0, the `props` option is required if you wish to accept `props` in a functional component. In 2.3.0+ you can omit the props option and all attributes found on the component node will be implicitly extracted as props.
>
> The reference will be HTMLElement when used with functional components because they’re stateless and instanceless.

You can see the original document [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Functional-Components).

I was so confused about the word "reference" in the second quote, what does this "reference" denotes?

Hope someone can help me figure out that, thanks my friend :)

Comment: Doesn't make much sense to me either but I suggest this is something to ask on [their forums](https://forum.vuejs.org/)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% certain, but I think it's referring to this situation:

```js
Vue.component('functional', {
  functional: true,
  render(h, ctx) {
    return h('button', ctx.data, ctx.children)
  }
})

Vue.component('full', {
  template: '<button><slot/></button>'
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$refs.func instanceof HTMLElement)
    console.log(this.$refs.full instanceof Vue)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <functional ref="func">Functional</functional>
  <full ref="full">Full</full>
</div>
```

If you get a ref to a functional component, you may not get a component instance back because functional components do not have a component instance itself.

It's best to think of a functional component as just a function. It isn't a "real" component.

The ref you get back depends on how the functional component is implemented. It is the responsibility of the functional component's render function to pass on the `ref` data to one of its children that it renders. In the example above, `ctx.data.ref` is equal to `'func'` and it gets assigned to the `<button>`, so in the root component `this.$refs.func` is equal to that DOM element. If I didn't pass on `ctx.data` to the button, then `this.$refs.func` will always be `undefined`.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense and fits with some of the earlier versions of the PR that added the note in the docs (https://github.com/vuejs/vuejs.org/pull/2145). Would definitely be better with some clarifying changes

Comment: But what if i replace `return h('button', ctx.data, ctx.children)` with `return h('full', ctx.data, ctx.children)`, then `this.$refs.func` now is actually referring to a vue component ?